# Classicthesis: Part name too long

Tags: classicthesis

I was wondering how I could change the .sty file in order to break the part name's line into two lines, since I find it too long. Writing \\ in the middle of the part's name doesn't compile. Below is a screen shot of what I get. I'd like it to be, e.g., "Generalidades de" \\ "procesos continuos".

The code to modify is the following:

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{ct@parts}}%
{%
    \newcommand{\ctparttext}[1]{\renewcommand{\ctparttext@keep}{#1}}
    \def\ctparttext@keep{} % Thanks to Ivo
    \def\ctparttext@print{\ctparttext@keep \gdef\ctparttext@keep{}}
    \titleformat{\part}[display]
    {\normalfont\ct@altfont\centering\large}%
    {\thispagestyle{empty}\partname~\MakeTextUppercase{\thepart}}{1em}%
    {\color{CTtitle}\spacedallcaps}[\bigskip\normalfont\normalsize\color{Black}
    \begin{quote}\ctparttext@print\end{quote}]
}{\relax}
```

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `\\` behaves badly inside `\MakeTextUppercase` unless protected.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\titlebreak}{\texorpdfstring{\\}{}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part[Generalidades de procesos continuos]
     {Generalidades de \titlebreak procesos continuos}

\end{document}
```

You need to add the optional argument in order that the title is not broken in the table of contents.

[image]

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much!!